# Android Studio Error compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep getting this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

Thinkgs I've tried doing:

- Deleting .gradle file and restarting android studio
- Project structure > JDK path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
- Downloaded every item in the SDK manager and installation was successful
- Project Structure > app > Build Tools Version tried whats on the list

**Note:** This error only appears when I try to run the program. If I never touch the run button all my code and builds are clean and successful, until I try running for the first time and it never goes if I try running again

*Other posts about this problem is very confusing since there is no right answer on how to do this and all the answers aren't supported with feedback*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove, last added dependency and then sync. If this error cleared mean, error in dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting this file:

```
c: \ users \ [myusername] \ .gradle \ caches \ 2.14.1
```

and restart the Android Studio

Comment: *Edited* I found it and deleted it and now will restart the ide